# Why doesn't my code save all the rows in the array in the table?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I have created a function in Swift to save the content of an array of dictionary in a table. I get 19 dictionaries in the array, but I find only two of them are saved in the database table. The console gives me positive feedback for all of the dictionaries.

This is my code:

```
func insert(feedback : [[String : Any]], inTable : String) {
    var insertStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
    let db1 = openDatabase()
    let keysArray = Array(feedback[0].keys)

    let keysString = keysArray.joined(separator: ", ")

    print("Modules: ", feedback.count)
    for i in 0...feedback.count - 1
    {
        let valuesArray = Array(feedback[i].values)
        var values = ""
        for value in valuesArray {
            values += "'\(value)',"
        }

        values = String(values.dropLast())

        let insertQuery = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO \(inTable) (\(keysString)) VALUES (\(values))"

        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db1, insertQuery, -1, &insertStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
            if sqlite3_step(insertStatement) == SQLITE_DONE {
                print("Successfully inserted row.")
            } else {
                print("Could not insert row.")
            }
        } else {
            print("INSERT statement could not be prepared.")
        }
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(insertStatement)
    sqlite3_close(db1)
}
```

Comment: FYI - your call to `sqlite3_finalize` is in the wrong place. It needs to be just before the `else` associated with `if sqlite3_prepare_v2...`.

Comment: How do you know SQLite supports all the data types you have?  You should instead create a model and save data as Data.

Comment: @ElTomato The code is converting everything to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your array has multiple dictionaries
Your dictionary can have more key-value pairs.
You now iterate in the array with different dictionaries.

Your problem is probably the 'keysArray':
let keysArray = Array(feedback[0].keys)  (0 should be dynamic)
you only use the keys from the first dictionary in the array